# how to configure your build for first time installation of android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am begainner in android app development.For practicing  i need to install android studio.So after installing i continously get dependency error stating that there is no cached version of dependency for offline mode since the place where i need to practise there is no internet connection.I have done many research about this topic but i could not find any of the solution.So plz anyone help me 
Thank you for precious time to help me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that but you need internet to make build. What happen, After installing studio, You have to update all your libraries and dependencies

Comment: i have done all of the possible solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8892572/nihal-srivastava can i get your fb id to talk with you ???

Answer (score 0):

have you installed android sdk?
if yes also you have install depandancy or library of its.

Comment: sorry but my reputation is not above 50 so, i can't